# Usage moderne : transformation de noms de famille par ajout d'article et suffixation

Tags: usage, régionalismes, noms-propres, france

Dans *La Petite Fadette* de George Sand, histoire qui met en scène, entre autres, le personnage du père Barbeau et de sa femme, la femme de celui-ci est appelé « la Barbeaude ».

Quel était, du temps de George Sand, l'effet de cette pratique ? Est-ce qu'il s'agit d'un usage des campagnes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le suffixe de *Barbeau**de*** marque le féminin mais ce n'est pas obligatoire.

La présence d'un article défini devant le patronyme est un usage très ancien, qui a peut-être même précédé l'absence d'article, en particulier quand les noms n'étaient encore que des surnoms. Il s'est souvent agglutiné au nom comme dans Lebègue, Leblanc, Lenoir, Lesourd, Legrand, Lepetit, etc.

Le contexte permet de déterminer comment interpréter cet article. Ce peut être une marque de notoriété pour des artistes (la Callas, la Castafiore, le Caravage), mais c'est plus souvent aujourd'hui, et déjà du temps de George Sand, associé au parler populaire. Cet article peut être parfois péjoratif (par exemple toutes les occurrences de *la Macronne* le sont) mais pas forcément.

Dans le cas de La Petite Fadette, *la Barbeaude* est représentatif du parler berrichon, comme *la Merlaude* est la fille ou l'épouse d'un dénommé Merlaud.

Il ne faut d'ailleurs pas aller très loin pour trouver un autre exemple de cet usage puisque la petite Fadette n'est autre que la petite-fille de la mère Fadet.